# Regex - Split URI on query and/or fragment

Tags: regex, uri

Using this definition of a URI

```
 <scheme name> : <hierarchical part> [ ? <query> ] [ # <fragment> ]
```

I want to split this into three groups; 1) scheme + heirarchy, 2) query, 3) fragment.

Some examples:

```
http://foo.com/bar?k1=v1&k2=v2#fragment = [http://foo.com/bar, ?k1=v1&k2=v2, #fragment]
http://foo.com/bar?k1=v1&k2=v2 = [http://foo.com/bar, ?k1=v1&k2=v2, ]
http://foo.com/bar#fragment = [http://foo.com/bar, , #fragment]
http://foo.com/bar = [http://foo.com/bar, , ]
```

At the moment I have `.+(\?[^#]+)(.*)?$` which handles case 1 and 2, 4 is no match which is okay but I'm having trouble trying to edit this to work for case 3.

It can be assumed that the URI is well formed, we care only about the presence of `?` and `#`.

The context is I have a URI input that may have a query and/or fragment part and I need to add additional query parameters to it. So evaluating the presence of each group I can figure out how my parameters should be inserted/appended to the URI.

Implementation is in Java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language are you using?  The Regex Engine behaves different in different languages implementation and commands (grep/sed/perl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(.+?)(\?.+?)?(#.+)?$
```

Answer (score 1):

http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex compares the accuracy of many url regexps against a test suite of urls & non-urls.  You could use that to pick one that trades off complexity vs accuracy.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/the-problem-with-urls.html is also a good article about the problems with using urls to extract regexps.

You might try something like

```
^(https?://[^?#]+)(\\?[^#]+)?(#.+)?$
```

if you know the input is a url, or use

```
(https?://[^?#\\s]+)(\\?[^#\\s]+)?(#\\S+)?
```

to find matching urls in text.

Answer (score 0):

`(.*)?` Wont produce a group because of the `?`.  Also, your regex only matches if a `?` Is in the url.  #3 has no `?`, so put a `?` After the `\?`.  Try:

```
.+(\??[^#]+)(.*)$
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Undesirable results using that expression:
    http://foo.com/bar?k1=v1&k2=v2#frag: 
    0: http://foo.com/bar?k1=v1&k2=v2#frag
    1: g
    2: 

    http://foo.com/bar?k1=v1&k2=v2: 
    0: http://foo.com/bar?k1=v1&k2=v2
    1: 2
    2: 

    http://foo.com/bar#frag:
    0: http://foo.com/bar#frag
    1: g
    2: 

    http://foo.com/bar: 
    0: http://foo.com/bar
    1: r
    2:

Comment: Try: .+(\??[^#]+)(.*)?$   Also, what kind of results?  Can you show some examples?

Comment: Those were the results, however, plugging in your expression looks like this http://grab.by/aVzX and the output looks like http://grab.by/aVA1

Comment: That was the modification you suggested then removed, the output does not change using the original answer.